# Transforming 2D Laser Profile Data to 3D Coordinates with Angle Considerations: Resolving Discrepancies

Tags: linear-algebra, 3d, projection, computer-vision

### General Understanding of what the project does:

I'm building a system where I take image(s) of an object at Various positions with a Line-Lazer being projected onto the object Vertically *(Perpendicular to the floor plane)* and ideally re-constructs this object in 3D space with a Point Cloud.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

NOTE: All these Images have a **Known Rotation Angle**, this is used as `slice_angle` later

**Generated from Slices:**
[image: Generated Point Cloud]

### How I went about Calculations from 2D to 3D Points:

I do preprocessing and gather the most bright Column on every Row, this way I build an X - Y map of points I want to transform into 3D

Then I use an undistortion algorithm on the points with Camera Matrix & Distortion matrix to get 2 undistorted X and Y points

From here, I make the Z point to be `Z = Undistorted X / tan ( Laser Angle )` which my lazer angle is 45 deg, so `Z = X` pretty much

After all 2D to 3D point conversions, I multiply all 3D points in that slice, with it's respective angle.

I do `X = X * cos(slice_angle)` and `Z = Z * sin(slice_angle)`, this way a slice at 45 degrees will be rotated that way.

UPDATE: Started using a rotation matrix, now I'm getting this for the cubic object:
[image]

Now I've got X,Y,Z coords for every point from the 2D image, rotated at it's respective `slice_angle`

Camera Matrix
\begin{pmatrix}
focalX & 0 & cY \\
0 & focalY & cY \\
0 & 0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}

Distortion Coefficients Matrix
\begin{pmatrix}
k1 \\
k2 \\
p1 \\
p2 \\
k3
\end{pmatrix}

```
            std::vector<cv::Point2f> srcPoints;
            srcPoints.push_back(cv::Point2f(static_cast<float>(middle), static_cast<float>(row)));

            std::vector<cv::Point2f> dstPoints;

            // Apply the camera calibration and distortion correction
            cv::undistortPoints(srcPoints, dstPoints, cameraMatrix, distCoeffs, cv::noArray(), newCameraMatrix);

            GLfloat offset = 0.05;

            GLfloat normalX = normalizeCoordinate(static_cast<float>(dstPoints[0].x), n_rows);
            GLfloat normalY = normalizeCoordinate(static_cast<float>(dstPoints[0].y), n_cols) + offset;

            double result = dstPoints[0].x / tan(45 * pi / 180); // Divide value by tangent of 45 degrees

            GLfloat normalZ = normalizeCoordinate(static_cast<float>(result), n_cols);


            GLfloat theta = (slice.angle +90) * pi / 180; // Convert angle to radians

            normalX = normalX * cos(theta); // Apply rotation matrix
            normalZ = normalZ * sin(theta); // Apply rotation matrix

            slice.list_3d_points.push_back(glm::vec3(normalX, normalY, normalZ)); // GLM::VEC3 works well with OpenGL
```

### ** The Problem: (The Issue)

This seems to work OK on round objects, *( Like a Mug, which is round on it's X and Z Axis )*

But when it comes to a Cube, my calculations break... Exhibit:

NOTE: Square-esque on X and Z axis

[image]

Here it is at 0* and 45*
[image]
[image]

And It's Software rendering: 
[image]
[image]
[image]

#### As you can see,

The Angled Slices don't align perfectly, and stuff seems to break...

I'm thinking of implementing a system where it finds offsets for everything to overlay correctly, but everything is quite relative so It would be hard to dynamically determine what is rendering in it's correct

#### Conclusion:

I'm looking for general advice & solutions for how I can potentially solve this Problem for non-circular shaped objects, **and or** Insight on if there are any parts that I can improve, really just tried to fix this up overall and get as many rendering working from Lazer Slices!

I'd really appreciate any criticism / advice on stuff I can do better!